# WAMP server, localhost is not working

Tags: localhost, wamp

My WAMP server localhost was broken when my Windows 7 updates automatically.

My port 80 is already used by IIS server.

I searched on website, many people suggested that I need to change the port 80 to port 8080 or something difference.

I updated `Listen:80` to `Listen:8080` and `ServerName localhost` to `ServerName localhost:8080`.

But it is still not working and leaves me a blank page.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on changing port 80 to 8080 for WAMP http://abishekravi.blogspot.com/2010/01/configuring-wamp-on-port-8080.html

Comment: can you run you http via command line and write the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto This link its working..

http://www.ttkalec.com/blog/resolving-yellow-wamp-server-status-freeing-up-port-80-for-apache/

Update: Using XAMP

After I’ve written this blog post I’ve figured out that XAMP, although very similar to WAMP, doesn’t force you to run Apache as a service, instead it can run it as a regular process. So I ended up using XAMP, and changed Apache port to 8080 so now everything works.

WAMP Issues

If you have Window 7 or later you may have come across issues with WAMP server trying to start Apache service on port 80 and failing.

There are many conflict and issues that might have come up.
Before you try anything, check if you have ZoneAlarm, Nod32, or any other program/firewall that might be blocking Apache server.
If you’re sure that firewall isn’t the problem here is a couple of fixes that you can try.

NOTE: After every fix you try, you must click on yellow WAMP icon and choose Restart All Services

Checking which process is causing the problem

Open Command Prompt window by typing cmd in Run command box or Start Search, and hit Enter.
Type in the following command:
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80
The last column of each row is the process identified (process ID or PID).
Identify which process or application is using the port by matching the PID against PID number in Task Manager.
If you don’t see PID column in your Task Manager you need to go to Processes tab -> View Menu -> Select Columns and choose PID from the list
Now, you may have identified application that reserves port 80, or you may have found out that System is using your port 80. That means that one of internal services is using your port, in which case continue reading further.
Conflict with Skype

If you found out that Skype is using your port 80, you need to change some settings in Skype. On Windows, Skype reserves port 80 which is used for HTTP. Apache requires this port. So if you’re running Skype, you must go to Tools > Options. Then in the Advanced section, select Connection. Un-check the box that says “Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connection“. Quit Skype and restart. The issue should be resolved.

Conflict with IIS Server

IIS Server and Apache are both web server that use port 80 so they might be in conflict. Try stopping IIS by:

Going into Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services
Right click on Default Web Site
Click on Stop option in the popup menu, and see of the listener on port 80 has cleared.
Conflict with MS SQL Server

MS SQL Server installs “SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)” that apparently defaults to 80. You can try stopping it to free up port 80.

Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
There find MSSQLSERVER (might be found also under SQL Server)
Double click it -> Click Stop
Under Startup type: choose Manual
Other Services that can cause conflicts

As described above for MS SQL Server:

Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
You can try stopping:
Web Deployment Agent Service
Windows Remote Management
Autodesk EDM Server
World Wide Web Publishing Service
There are probably more of them, but this where the ones that I tryed.

Try turning off HTTP driver directly

If you’ve tried everything mentioned above and your WAMP server is still not working you could try this (which eventually helped me).

Right click on My Computer icon -> Properties
Go to Device Manager
Click on View menu and chooseShow hidden devices
Now from the list choose Non-Plug and Play devices
Double click HTTP -> go to Driver
For Type choose Disabled
Restart your computer
After your computer boots up you should be able to start up WAMP server.

If everything else fails

You could try changing Apache server to listen to some other port other than port 80.

Click on yellow WAMP icon in your taskbar
Choose Apache -> httpd.conf
Inside find these two lines of code:

Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
and change them to something like this (they are not one next to the other):

Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:8080
Restart all services, and try typing localhost:8080 into your browser.
WAMP server should now be working.

Answer (score 30):

Wamp Server localhost not working.
problems port 80 is closed. Icon Color Yellow

Solution:

wamp icon click > Apache > Service > Service Install

wamp icon click > All Services Restart

Icon Green its Work

Comment: Dude, you are the real mvp

Answer (score 6):

Check Your **Skype**, I had the problem because skype reserved port 80 for incoming calls, I unchecked it , and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `skype` installed, close it completely.

If you have `sql server` installed, go to:

`Control panel` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `Services`

And stop `SQL Server Reporting Services`

Port 80 must be free now. Click on Wamp icon -> `Restart All Services`

Answer (score 2):

You please change the port 80 to **port 7080** or something difference.
Dont use 8080. It might be busy in most case.

Updated Listen 80 to Listen:7080 and ServerName localhost to ServerName localhost:7080.

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to disable the IIS service from the services snapin

(use the start menu -> search programs and files -> services.msc to launch the snapin )

This will stop IIS using port 80. Then change Apache back to using port 80.

Answer (score 0):

First stop IIS from startmenu by typing IIS manager, 
Edit `c:/wamp/wampmanager.tpl` file so the WAMP menu points to `localhost:80`.
Find `http://localhost` and change it to `htttp://localhost:80` also, if you think something else has already grabbed port 80, that is why its not working..,then,
Run

```
wampmanager->Apache->Service->Test port 80
```

This will launch a command window and tell you what is using port 80.
Whatever it is, will need to be re-configured to use another port or for example if its IIS and you dont use IIS it should be un-installed.
Further you can use `'net stop'` command to stop desired service.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is:

1. Right click on `Computer` -> `Properties` -> `Device manager`.
2. `View` -> `Show hidden devices`.
3. Choose `Non-plug and plug drivers` -> `HTTP` -> `Disable`.
4. Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Best try for windows:
Open up cmd.
run the following command:
**C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.17**
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\ Should be replaced with the path where your Apache is installed.
you use \ because \ is an escape character ;)
If the service could not start it will return the error.
For me it was the DocumentRoot was invalid :)