# Wampserver stop working after a few minutes while it lights green

Tags: localhost, wampserver

Wamp Server stops after some minutes and I always have to do "Restart all service", it works a few minutes then it stops again and I have to do "Restart all services" again. After a few minutes it will stop ofcourse....

**Solved**

I have run this command **netsh winsock reset** and problem is solved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968495/wamp-server-localhost-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You can add these 2 parameters to your httpd.conf file. As the comment suggests the issue can be with your network card and/or drivers for it.

```
# AcceptFilter: On Windows, none uses accept() rather than AcceptEx() and
# will not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful for network
# adapters with broken driver support, as well as some virtual network
# providers such as vpn drivers, or spam, virus or spyware filters.
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Just before this line

```
# Supplemental configuration
```

Comment: I have added it, but the problem returns again :/

Comment: I have run this command `netsh winsock reset` and problem is solved